Looking for a Japanese(?) sci-fi comedy about a restaurant in space
Recently took a flight on Delta that had a lot of international films. I watched one that I think was Japanese. Basic plot was a young couple that ran a restaurant on an 'exit ramp' on the space highway and the stories of various people and aliens passing through. It also featured a superhero by the name of "Captain Socks", animated birds, and hamburgers. It was sci-fi camp. 
Alas, I don't remember the title of the film. I thought it'd be easy to find, but Delta doesn't list international films on its web site's current listing of films. It seem quite new...would guess it had come out in the past couple of years. 

Sounds like the Japanese comedy Galaxy Turnpike from 2015. From an online review:

“Galaxy Turnpike” begins in 2265 on an off-ramp from Route 246666, which connects Earth to a space colony located between Jupiter and Saturn. Here a married couple, Noa (Shingo Katori) and Noe (Haruka Ayase), run the venerable fast-food joint Sandsand Burger, now in its 150th year of operation.
Their customers, space aliens all, are a varied lot. At a corner table a shy doctor (Kanji Ishimaru) sits with a sketchy pimp (Koji Yamamoto) flipping through a photo album of alien hookers, some of whom look vaguely human. At a nearby booth a bespectacled bureaucrat (Yasunori Danta) taps at his PC, with chirping cartoon birds, a yapping cartoon dog and a mincing elderly mime (Kazuyuki Asano) hovering nearby. Don’t ask why.

Here's the, er, colorful trailer:




That's it! Thanks! I kept searching for 'highway' when I should have been searching for 'turnpike'. It's a really fun film, BTW. Makes me realize I need to explore what's coming out of Japan a lot more.
